# Создать метку [jpql]

Tags: предложение, создание-метки

В последнее время я много работаю с `JPQL` и задаю много вопросов по этой теме. `JPQL` - это, если говорить грубо, аналог `SQL`, только объектно-ориентированный, предназначенный для работы с ORM.

Я предлагаю создать метку для данного вопроса, потому что у нас на сайте её нет, а у американцев есть. Ну и ставить метку [sql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) для вопросов про `JPQL` не вполне корректно на мой взгляд.

Кто-нибудь из джавистов может создать метку [jpql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jpql)? Вот её описание с англоязычного стека *(дословное)*:

> The Java Persistence Query Language (JPQL) is a platform-independent
> object-oriented query language defined as part of the Java Persistence
> API specification.

> The [Java Persistence query language (JPQL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_Query_Language) is used to define searches
> against persistent entities independent of the mechanism used to store
> those entities. As such, JPQL is "portable", and not constrained to
> any particular data store. The Java Persistence query language is an
> extension of the Enterprise JavaBeans query language (EJB QL), adding
> operations such as bulk deletes and updates, join operations,
> aggregates, projections and subqueries.
>
> - [JPQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html)
> - [JPQL Chapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbtg.html) from Java EE 6 Tutorial

Comment: Вы можете создать ее сами

Comment: @avp да, я уж понял, спасибо)